# Why does Joe Pesci stand up twice and get "taken out back" by Letterman? What's the actual joke here?

Tags: david-letterman-show

[image: screenshot from the Letterman YouTube clip "Joe Pesci Is Not Here To Amuse You | Letterman" https://youtu.be/f4LUsUv-KC8]

The description of the Letterman YouTube clip *Joe Pesci Is Not Here To Amuse You | Letterman* is

> The "Goodfellas" star talks about golfing with his buddy Jack Nicholson and does his best Madonna impression. (Air date: 4/29/94)

I'm not sure Pesci actually attempts a Madonna impression, but twice he got up as if he'd done something wrong; the first time he was even "taken out back" by Letterman and Pesci pulled his jacket over his head to hide his face.

The second time he used an expletive, but as far as I can tell he did not the first time.

These are cued at the beginning of the setups for each:

- [03:14](https://youtu.be/f4LUsUv-KC8?t=194)
- [04:43](https://youtu.be/f4LUsUv-KC8?t=283)

The Audience seems to understand why Pesci gets up and finds it funny, but I think I'm missing the context.

**Question:** Why does Joe Pesci stand up twice and get "taken out back" by Letterman? What's the actual joke here?

There must be some context outside of this short clip that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its just because he swears.  He says "fucking" on each occasion.  One is silenced on the youtube clip but you can make it out through lip reading, the second clip is more obvious.

The Late Show airs on CBS, so Network Television, which is absolutely banned by the FCC from broadcasting profanity before 10pm.  The Late Show broadcasts after this time of day, but I believe CBS internal rules still ban profanity today, as can be seen in this section from [The Late Show with Steven Colbert](https://youtu.be/7Hx51qTg0bc?si=CBoSoZ0NdQPeOYoy&t=224).

As @Valorum states in a comment, I think Letterman plays into this through enacting something like "taking a mad-dog out the back to shoot them", and the audience is playing along.  The scale of the reaction makes me wonder if they were prepared before the show for a joke of this kind.

Comment: It's also an *Old Yeller* reference. Joe is [metaphorically speaking] a mad dog that can't be controlled.

Comment: That makes sense @Valorum.  I suspect it was planned.  It's only internal CBS rules that were broken, not the much more severe FCC rules.  The audience reaction is bigger than I would expect, so it feels like they are in on the joke.

Comment: OK now that you point it out, yes I can just barely notice the audio blanking on the first clip. Yes makes perfect sense now. Geez it's been so long since I've heard a native English speaker talk (except for news) and Pesci's not making it any easier for me. *Thanks!*

Comment: Yeah, @uhoh, even as a native English speaker it wasn't that obvious until I watched the first clip a couple of times too.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Madonna and David Letterman]

David Letterman retrieves Madonna's Top Ten List, March 31, 1994 (YouTube, [Letterman channel](https://youtu.be/BMQWR2v9opQ?si=ScsJJkLk2SD-H-Ee&t=719))

As mentioned in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/121121/101022), Joe Pesci was taken to the woodshed for saying the F word.

This was less than a month after Madonna appeared on *The Late Show with David Letterman* on March 31st, 1994, in what became a highly publicized and controversial appearance where Madonna used the F word fourteen times during the interview. It was in fact the most censored talk show episode in history. There is even a lengthy [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna_on_the_Late_Show_with_David_Letterman_in_1994) about the incident.

When Pesci accidentally did the same thing during his interview, Letterman's humorous exaggerated reaction, as well as the audience reaction would have been well understood at the time of the broadcast.

Comment: Great context. +1

Comment: As a side note, I went through the video looking for a good screenshot to include. I was trying to find one of Madonna puffing on her cigar, however every time she puffed on the cigar she closed her eyes which would have made a screenshot look like she was just blinking. Finally I came across Dave reaching "underneath" Madonna to get the top ten  list that she had placed there, and I thought well, there's the shot right there. Only afterwards did I notice that Wikipedia has virtually the same shot in their article on the incident.